# Master Detail Template Not Displaying Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, master-detail

I used the Master - Detail application to create a new project in xcode. Each time I run my program, the rows are not visible in the master view. Thanks in advance! Please check my code below...

MasterViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @class DetailViewController;
 @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
 @property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
 @end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h" 
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  ***emphasized text***initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)  [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear =    self.splitViewController.isCollapsed;
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
if (!self.objects) {
    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

 #pragma mark - Segues
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue  destinationViewController] topViewController];
    [controller setDetailItem:object];
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
}
}

 #pragma mark - Table View
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 1;
 }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
return self.objects.count;
 }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
return cell;
 }

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
 }
@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface DetailViewController ()
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
#pragma mark - Managing the detail item
-(void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;
   // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
  }
 }

-(void)configureView {
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
if (self.detailItem) {
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
 }
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self configureView];
}
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 @end
```

Comment: A picture is not needed in this case, all it'd show is an empty view. What *is* needed is your code (and Interface Builder files' setup if you are using outlets). First of all, if you follow a tutorial and are sure that the datasource methods are good, make sure the table view `datasource` is set correctly.

Comment: @A-Live , Thank you for your response. I checked the datasource and it was set up correctly. I also deleted and reinstall xcode. I still have the same problem, I am still working on it thou! Thanks so much for reaching out...

Comment: You really shouldn't have to reinstall Xcode unless something fundamental gets broken. Instead of taking such measures try to use breakpoints at the key methods and see whether they are called and do perform as expected. Verify that the desired view controller is presented, the table view is added to views hierarchy, you might also have to ask the table view to reload data at some point depending on how you are working with it. Finally, your cells might be impossible to see, e.g. have 0 height and no separators. And don't forget to add your code to the question if you need a good feedback.

Comment: lol, funny how i have gotten 6 downvotes already. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Perhaps because of a low quality of the question. If you multiply the time needed to read it and consider giving yet another broad answer to yet another broad question by the number of users who do that the result doesn't look good, does it ? Consider adding your code or links to relevant screenshots of interface builder to better describe the problem and remove irrelevant parts.

Comment: @A-Live, Ok, I understand. Thank you for the feed back. The reason I didn't add the codes was because there were directly from the master - detail application template. I didn't edit them. Anyways I am editing my question now and I will add the codes. Thanks again for reaching out! very grateful :)

Comment: @A-Live, just finished editing it. Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks normal at this code, something must be off at the storyboard or project setup, for example you might have cleared or changed datasource outlet of the table view or changed the initially displayed view controller.

Comment: @A-Live, I believe so. I noticed that when I run the app in the simulator and then, left click and drag the table view, the rows display. If I release the left click, the rows disappear...

Answer (score 0):

I figured, if you scale the size of the device to 75% and 100%, the rows will display. I guess this has something to do with xcode.